# Inflating/folding out panel in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a simple Android application that should contain a webview and two control-panels.
One small control panel should be always visible and the other one should inflate when a special button on the smaller control-panel is clicked.
Implementing the webview is not a problem. But I am not sure which layouts and containers I should use to implement the control-panels on the right side of screen.
Is there a common way to get these control-panels? And which Layouts and Containers should I use?

Here is a picture of how I want to arrange the screen.
[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MotionLayout](http://%20https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout), you can do this with very basic motion layout ,you are going to have contraintset for invisible panel and visible panel.

think of first contraint set `ConstraintSet`as constraints that you would use when side panel is not there another `ConstraintSet` when it is there , then you are going to have a `Transition` with `OnClick` attributes , and you reference a button in the visible side panel , when that button is pressed motion layout will interpolate between first and second constraint sets. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#side_panel) is similar example

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Is there maybe somewhere a tutorial how to implement a Side Panel using the MationLayout?

Comment: they will shrink the main view only if the side panel is constrained to the main view , you just constraint it to parent only and it won't happen , also documentation of constraint layout has everything that you need to implement this also don't look for exact solution , trying yourself is how you become better,  believe me it is really easy , just basic constraint layout invest some time to learn it , don't see example without understanding constraintlayout